# Getting invalid token in Firebase Cloud Messaging in cURL command and postman

Tags: firebase, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

guys, I'm trying to get information about app instance and I'm also trying to subscribe an app instance to a Google Cloud Messaging topic but the problem is whenever I try to use the `server key` it throws me the error of `invalid token` and when I try to use the `web api key` it gives me `unauthorized`

I've tried it using postman but the results are the same. Can somebody tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong

Here is the screenshot of the request that I'm sending using postman

[image: Postman Request Image]

and here is the screenshot of the request that I'm sending using curl

[image: Curl Request Image]

Comment: The image you provided shows the response. Could you also add in the *payload* that you're sending?

Comment: @AL. you mean this one ?? https://imgur.com/a/Io0Gt

Comment: Nope. The payload is what you put in the body of your cURL POST request. See my the SO documentation I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging/26577/sending-downstream-messages-using-postman#t=201612270331384845629)

Comment: @AL. well this is a get request with which I'm trying to retrieve the information about app instance 

 so I can't place anything in the body of the request as mentioned here to make a get request https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances

Comment: @AL. do you have any idea of what is it that I'm doing wrong

Comment: Oh. I see. I thought you were sending a message.. One thing for certain is that you should focus on the `InvalidRegistrationToken` error, since you shouldn't use the Web API Key with FCM. Are you positive that the token you're including in the request is not altered in any way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155798/discussion-between-gardezi-and-al).